# How to create dynamic 301 redirect urls

Tags: redirect

Is it possible to create dynamic 301 redirect urls ?

I have a dating site and the url format is like `/dating/united_states_singles/`. A few months ago, I changed it to `/free-dating/united_states/` (added free and removed singles). When I checked on Google webmaster tool, both URLs (old and new) are indexed, which create duplicate title and description tags.

Is it possible to create 301 redirect for all old urls to new urls format?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a windows IIS server url the url rewrite module
http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite